# Is there a way to pass command line arguments to mrjob?

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

Is there a way to pass command line arguments to mrjob, for example if you have a json file and you want to find how many keys have a certain, repeated value? In particular I have several json objects that have a location key and an item value so I want to find how many locations have item x and count the number of locations. A location may have multiple instances of an item.

I've read you can pass it in the config but I have a requirement for the user to be able to choose the item from the command line at the time the program is ran.